# Journey Builder Ad Audience - behaviour and issues

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions

I am doing some testing of the *Ad Audience* activity in Journey Builder. I'm hoping someone can confirm/clarify some behaviour for me.

---

**Cannot Select Existing Audience**

When configuring the activity, it only ever lets me create a new audience. Is it not possible to select an existing audience that was configured using a DE?

---

**DE Created by Activity**

The DE created by the activity is super basic - just email address. When setting up an audience using a DE, you can do a lot more in terms of matching by additional criteria, but this doesn't seem possible with the JB activity. Is this just a limitation?

---

**New Journey Versions lose configuration**

I can configure the activity, activate the journey, and everything works (ie: a DE gets created, the audience is created in Ad Studio, and journey contacts get added to the audience). However, if I then create a new version of the journey and click on the Ad Audience activity in the draft, it looks as though it has lost all config (ie: as if I dragged a completely new one onto the canvas). Does anyone know if this is a bug or how it should be working?

---

Overall, it seems like the *Ad Audience* activity (aside from creating the audience) is doing nothing except adding the email address of the contact in the journey to a data extension. Is that all it does?

I'm thinking if that is indeed all it does, then I might be better configuring my own audience with additional matching criteria, then using a query to add relevant contacts from the journey to the audience.

Thanks